# Как поместить значения таблицы в одну строку?

Tags: php, mysql, sql

```
<?php
require_once "connect.php";
$query = mysqli_query($db, 
"SELECT products.name, products.description, products.price, categories.category 
FROM products 
LEFT JOIN product_category ON product_category.product_id=products.id 
LEFT JOIN categories ON product_category.category_id=categories.id");


?>
<table>
  <tr>
    <th>Продукт</th>
    <th>Описание</th>
    <th>Цена</th>
    <th>Категория</th>
</tr>
  <? while($val = mysqli_fetch_assoc($query)){?>
    <tr>
    <td>
  <?=$val['name']?>
  </td>
  <td>
  <?=$val['description']?>
  </td>
  <td>
  <?=$val['price']?>
  </td>
  <td>
  <?=$val['category']?>
  </td>
    </tr>
 <?}?>
</table>
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Я хочу, что-бы похожие категории были в 1 линию(т.е. есть продукт Водка, он относится и к продуктам и к алкоголю, и Я хочу, что бы эти две категории были в 1 линию, а не дублировали продукты). Но не могу понять как это сделать.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
<table>
  <tr>
    <th>Продукт</th>
    <th>Описание</th>
    <th>Цена</th>
    <th>Категория</th>
</tr>
 <? $timed_val = ""?>
  <? while($val = mysqli_fetch_assoc($query)){?>
  <?if $timed_val != $val['name']{?>
    <tr>
    <td>
  <?=$val['name']?>
  </td>
  <td>
  <?=$val['description']?>
  </td>
  <td>
  <?=$val['price']?>
  </td>
  <td>
  <?=$val['category']?>
  </td>
    </tr>
<? $timed_val = $val['name'] ?>
<? }else{ ?>
  <td>
  <?=$val['category']?>
  </td>
 <?}}?>
</table>
```

Возможно где-то опечатался, сейчас не начем проверить работоспособность.

Comment: спасибо, Я бы не додумался до такого решения)

Answer (score 0):

Я так понял необходимо групировка товара по полю продукт.
Помечаешь выведенную ['name'] в отдельную переменную, далее сраниваешь новую ['name'] с прошлой, если совпадают то выводишь  только ['categori'].
иначе выводишь следующую строку.

Comment: Т.е. завернуть поле нейм в условие?

Comment: нет, завернуть все тело цикла в условие, иначе структура таблицы нарушиться.

Comment: можешь, пример кинуть как бы ты сделал?

Comment: написал пример, да и в целом не еркомендую использовать mysqli, используйте ОРМ или хотя бы PDO;  Иначе скоро столкнетесь с большим количеством уязвимостей.

Comment: Я только начал изучать sql и БД в целом, но спасибо. Хотя бы будет представление, что еще надо изучить.